# Ford not starting on key turn after acc

Tags: ford, starting, alternator, mondeo

I've got a mk3 Mondeo 1.8petrol zetec. It had bad alternator so I left it laying up for 6 months until I got around to getting a new one, but 3 weeks ago with the bad alternator in it, I started car up to keep the engine in good useful order for when I got fixed.

When I started it, it was fine for 5mins, but then spluttered and cut out. I assumed it was the alternator after draining my battery, so thought nothing of it. I got a new alternator and fully charged the battery, put it into the car and tried to start it but got nothing - no clicking, just accessories and red dash lights nothing more. Next day I went out and tried again - still nothing, but now the fuel pump relay clicking like crazy on acc so I pulled off the fuel line that connects to the fuel rail and petrol came streaming out, so my pump is working fine but the relay has constant clicking and even the wire clip that runs under the fuel rail is clicking too. So when I undo the clip under fuel rail the clicking stops in the relay. I still have no crank but I did jump the signal wire from the positive terminal in my battery and it cranks then but still no start.

I dont know what else to do. I did just today end up taking off the starter motor and cleaned all terminals to see if it sorts my problem tomorrow when I put it back on, but the constant clicking is stressing me from the fuel pump relay. I even swapped out the relay with a similar type but the clicking is still there. Any help would be really appreciated - I'm new to this type of online looking for help, so thanks in advance for any advice you can recommend.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you get All the cables connected to the battery properly?

Comment: What Moab said. Ignore the clicking fuel pump - it may a symptom of a missing connection at the replaced alternator - the same (or similar) missing connection that may be preventing the starter from operating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking noises when attempting to start your car are almost always a symptom of a bad battery and/or bad connection between the battery and the starter motor.I wouldn't worry about the fuel line, try the following things and then go back to that if there is no change.

Things to check:
 - Clean the terminals that connect to the battery and then reattach them, sometimes rust / residue from old batteries can cause a bad connection here, especially if they look crusty or discoloured.
 - Check the battery voltage is over 12V (using a voltmeter)
 - Try jumping the car from another to see if it will start
 - If those three things don't clear the problem then unplug and re-attach the replaced alternator

Hope that clears up your problem.

Comment: Hi lads thanks for all replys i never got round to the car today to put starter back in but i did clean the terminals an flap wheeled the ground cables an positive cable to the alternater clip i did clip in  the clip but ill try undoing the power clip tomorra definitly give everything the once over again an see what happens ill let ye.s know how i get on tomorrow roughly lunch time i should be done by and plz god its all good or off to the scrap yard with it i hav3nt much paitence i get like this over stupid things like this

Comment: Hi everyone tried everything yous told me i evend up taken starter off cleannin every connection a nothing clickin fuel relay still goin 90 on acc whe i give the extra turn clock and all the miles time go off the display an not a sound only constant clickin i swapped the relay for the lights which is same but does exactly same so im stuck and confused what it could be Anyone anything else i can try or look for  feel like im going to explode over this i. Fumeing i knoww its something simple